# Webapi get method not called from Angular app

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular.

I have WebAPI controller, which contains get method to return some data.

It is working fine while launching it separately from browser.

While calling the same method from Angular app, the get method is not called in WebAPI controller.

Here is my code for calling get method.

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:49422/api/CustomerRegister');
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In angular , you need to subscribe to the http.get method

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:49422/api/CustomerRegister').subscribe(result => this.result =result);
```

Comment: sure, i m posting from mobile. hope it worked. mark if that helped

Comment: Hi, Now I am try to call the post method like below. this.http.post('http://localhost:51690/api/ZS/PostEmployee',{"EmployeeId": 166,"EmployeeName" :"'empname910", "EmployeeCity": "empcityw11"}).subscribe(test => console.log(test.json()));                                                                    
 It's working fine while calling from POSTMAN. But not worked while calling from AngularJS... any suggestions ?